# not able to fetch remote json link from local html file in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I want to fetch a json from link [https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050]
When I open in browser it dumps the json on screen; good as expected but when I try to fetch this link from javascript it gives me cors error.

Please help me by giving a working solution. I am not a pro programmer.

Preferably I don't want a server in middle. Server solution is considered as last option if not possible without it. Currently I am using nodejs server in middle.

[Error I get when I run code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQUa5.png)

I tried with this code in javascript

```
fetch('https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is due to **cors** header missing. CORS stands for cross orging resource sharing. This header tells the server/backend to permit any origins (like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) except its own from which a browser should permit loading resources.

Here is the fix to your code

```js
fetch('https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
```

Comment: This did'nt work. Error
`Access to fetch at 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header. It's useless on a request.